# adding an EventListener to an Enter_Frame event function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I was just curious if I add an a EventListener such as `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);` 
Inside an ENTER_FRAME event function will it add an instance of that MouseEvent Listener every frame? 
Here is my code now just wondering if this is bad practice:

```
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, engineLogic);
```

inside my engineLogic function:

```
    //Max objects for rock throwers on left 
        if (aXPositionArray.length == 0)
        {
            //Remove listener to add more and make button turn grey etc
            rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSpawnSideRockThrowers);
            rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.visible = false;
        }else
        if (aXPositionArray.length != 0)
        {
            rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSpawnSideRockThrowers);
            rockThrowerSpawnScreen.left.visible = true;
            trace("LISTENER");
        }
```

or does it only add it once and checks the function every frame?

Comment: You subscribe a certain method to a certain event as many times as you call **addEventListener**. Flash Player does exactly as you instruct rather than overthink it and correct possible errors.

Comment: Yes, it will, in short. And yes, it's "bad practice" in terms of some function would get called increasingly more times per frame. You'd better add a listener *once* and then check inside that listener for conditions, whether it can be clicked with result, and update the object's fields accordingly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the information